# Rest framework: different serializer for input and output data on post/put operations

Tags: python, django, rest, web-services, django-rest-framework

Lets say I have these models:

```
class Download(MPTTTimeStampedModel):
    endpoint = models.ForeignKey(EndPoint, related_name="downloads",)

class EndPoint(TimeStampedModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_(u"Nombre"))
    url = models.CharField(max_length=2000, verbose_name=_(u"Url"))
```

These serializers:

```
class DownloadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Download
        fields = ('id', 'endpoint')  

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, validated_data):
        ...


class EndPointSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = EndPoint
        fields = ('id', 'name', 'url')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        ...

    def update(self, validated_data):
        ...
```

And this generic api view:

```
class DownloadList(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Download.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DownloadSerializer
```

This will allow me to create a download by sending a json representation looking like this:

```
{
    'id': null,
    'endpoint': 19
}
```

And upon creation, the web service will send me back the data with the id from the database. Now, I actually want the web service to send me back not just the endpoint id but a complete representation of the object, Something like this:

```
{
    'id': null,
    'endpoint': {
        'id': 19,
        'name': 'my endpoint',
        'url': 'http://www.my-endpoint.com/'
    }
}
```

I would manage this with this serializer:

```
class DownloadDetailedSerializer(DownloadSerializer): 
    endpoint = EndPointSerializer(many = False, read_only=False)
```

And now the actual question: how do i tell my generic view to use this last serializer for the returned data while keeping the original DownloadSerializer for the input?

**EDIT**: as @neverwalkeralone suggested the way to go is creating a custom field and overriding to_representation method. But that lead me to an exception in the line *serializer = EndPointSerializer(value)*, and after some testing I found out that it would be better to inherit my custom field from RelatedField. That implies overriding to_internal_value too. So here is what finally got the job done:

```
class EndPointField(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = EndPointSerializer(value)
        return serializer.data

    def to_internal_value(self, instance):
        endpoint = EndPoint.objects.get(pk=instance)
        return endpoint

    def get_queryset(self):
        return EndPoint.objects.all()
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define custom field, use `to_representation` method to customize output format:

```
class EndPointField(serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, value):
        serializer = EndPointSerializer(value)
        return serializer.data

    def get_queryset(self):
        return models.EndPoint.objects.all()
```

And use it in `DownloadSerializer` for endpoint field:

```
class DownloadSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    endpoint = EndPointField()

    class Meta:
        model = Download
        fields = ('id', 'endpoint')
```

**UPD**

Based on Kilian Perdomo Curbelo feedback `EndPointField`'s `to_representation` value should be replaced with endpoint instance:

```
def to_representation(self, value):
    endpoint = EndPoint.objects.get(pk=value.pk)
    serializer = EndPointSerializer(endpoint)
    return serializer.data
```

Comment: Maybe im doing something wrong but tried this and still have the same problem. My input and output data use the same serialization, EndPointField in this case. What i meant is, I need my web service to accept the input in a format (just the primary key for related endpoint) and return the created object in a different format (a dictionary with the complete information from the database)

Comment: @KilianPerdomoCurbelo yes, with this method you will post only endpoint id. And for read_only request endpoint field will return detailed endpoint information. Can you show what you tried? And input/output data?

Comment: You need to use `DownloadSerializer` serializer in view. And `EndPointField ` should be only field in this serializer.

Comment: neverwalkeralone your original code was not working, reason being EndPointField inheriting from PrimaryKeyRelatedField. That lead me to and exception in the serializer = EndPointSerializer(value) line, not sure why but i think because that "value" was not the type EndPointSerializer was expecting. Long story short, after some changes with different results, I finally found the right code. Your hint was on point though so i consider your solution valid. I am updating the code in my comment.

Comment: @KilianPerdomoCurbelo thank you for feedback. I've updated my answer also, it should work now.